# Spam no formulário de contato

Tags: php, formulário, spam

Olá.
Estou sofrendo com spams no formulário de contato do meu Portfólio. Já coloquei os campos 'nome', 'email' e 'mensagem' como obrigatórios e com os testes que fiz, não é possível enviar sem preencher esses campos.
Mas a cada hora chega no meu email esse formulário enviado só com o campo email preenchido, são emails aleatórios.
Como consigo fazer isso parar? Há algum jeito de fazer sem colocar Captcha no meu formulário?

**Esse é o meu formulário:**

```
<form action="sendemail.php" method="post" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">

                          <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text"  placeholder="Nome" class="form-control" name="nome" id="nome" required="Preencha o seu nome">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">

                          <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">

                          <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Assunto" class="form-control" name="assunto" id="assunto">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">

                          <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <textarea placeholder="Mensagem" class="form-control" name="mensagem" id="mensagem" rows="3" required=""></textarea>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
                      </div>

                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

**E esse é o arquivo que faz o envio do formulário:**

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// Debes editar las próximas dos líneas de código de acuerdo con tus preferencias
$email_to = "marciasprates@hotmail.com";
$email_subject = "Contato | Meu Portfólio";
$email_from = "marciaprates.com";


// Aquí se deberían validar los datos ingresados por el usuario
if(!isset($_POST['nome']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['assunto']) ||
!isset($_POST['mensagem'])) {

echo "<b>Não foi possível enviar o formulário. </b><br />";
echo "Por favor, tente novamente!<br />";
die();
}

$email_message = "Formulário do meu Portfólio:\n\n";
$email_message .= "Nome: " . $_POST['nome'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Assunto: " . $_POST['assunto'] . "\n\n";
$email_message .= "Mensagem: " . $_POST['mensagem'] . "\n\n";


// Ahora se envía el e-mail usando la función mail() de PHP
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

echo "<b>O formulário foi enviado com sucesso!</b>";

}
?>

<script>
  setTimeout('window.location.href="index.html"',1700)
</script>﻿
```

Alguém poderia por favor me ajudar? Já não aguento mais esses emails chegando a cada hora só com o email preeenchido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [`isset();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) verifica se a variável foi iniciada, mesmo estando vazia ela estará iniciada, com isso sempre a condição que você criu não irá funcionar, o que você pode fazer é o seguinte, trocar o `isset();` um [`strlen();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php), por exemplo:

```
<?php
if(strlen($_POST['email']) > 0) {

// Debes editar las próximas dos líneas de código de acuerdo con tus preferencias
$email_to = "marciasprates@hotmail.com";
$email_subject = "Contato | Meu Portfólio";
$email_from = "marciaprates.com";


// Aquí se deberían validar los datos ingresados por el usuario
if(!strlen($_POST['nome']) > 0 ||
!strlen($_POST['email']) > 0 ||
!strlen($_POST['assunto']) > 0 ||
!strlen($_POST['mensagem']) > 0) {

echo "<b>Não foi possível enviar o formulário. </b><br />";
echo "Por favor, tente novamente!<br />";
die();
}

$email_message = "Formulário do meu Portfólio:\n\n";
$email_message .= "Nome: " . $_POST['nome'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Assunto: " . $_POST['assunto'] . "\n\n";
$email_message .= "Mensagem: " . $_POST['mensagem'] . "\n\n";


// Ahora se envía el e-mail usando la función mail() de PHP
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

echo "<b>O formulário foi enviado com sucesso!</b>";

}
?>

<script>
  setTimeout('window.location.href="index.html"',1700)
</script>
```

Certamente existe outras maneiras de fazer, mas atualmente essa é a que acho mais pratica no seu caso.

Teste e veja se funciona conforme o que precisa.

**OBS.:** O que você pode também ajuda a bloquear spam é adicionar um [**captcha**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) a seu formulário, assim vai evitar o preenchimento por robôs.

Comment: Obrigada, vou tentar aqui e ver se vai funcionar.

Comment: De nada, eu atualizei a resposta e coloquei um OBs, creio que também vá te ajudar também.

Comment: O recapcha da google é bem tranquilo quando é humano preenchendo ele só é aquele bixo chato quando a alguma suspeita, alias funcionou direitinho ?

Comment: Até então o strlen(); ta funcionando.
Vou esperar até amanhã pra ver se não recebo  mais nenhum formulário vazio. Se não receber, vou deixar só com o strlen. Se não, vou testar o recapcha.
 Obrigada pela ajuda :)

Comment: show outra dica, é essa, da uma lida nessa pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php ela valida pra saber se o dado preenchido é um email, creio que é uma validação relevante para seu caso, vai garanti que o usuário realmente preencheu um email valido

Comment: Opa, valeu. Vou tentar adaptar ao meu.

Answer (score 1):

Testa alterar o isset por **strlen()**, pois isset só verifica se está existe já o strlen( ) > 0 verifica se a String está vazia. Mas, o ideial mesmo é utilizar o [Recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html).

Comment: Obrigada Mauriney, pela dica. Vou testar o strlen() até amanhã, se não surtir efeito eu testo com o recaptcha mesmo.